# como estilizar o texto selecionado JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

o que quero é pegar o texto selecionado do JTextPane e edita-lo, por exemplo: mudar a cor da fonte, o tamanho e a família. O problema é que depois que mudo uma vez o texto selecionado, ele não muda mais.Meu código é esse ai, só tá mudando a cor da letra , usei html(não sei se é a melhor maneira).

```
String textoSelecionado = edtEditor.getText().toString();
nova = textoSelecionado.replace(textoSelecionado,"<span color='red'>"+textoSelecionado+"</span>");
String start = edtEditor.getText().substring(0,edtEditor.getSelectionStart());
String end = edtEditor.getText().substring(edtEditor.getSelectionEnd(),edtEditor.getText().length());
edtEditor.setText(start+nova+end);
```

Comment: consegui usando a classe SimpleAttributeSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema com esse método:

```
 public void styleFont(boolean bold, boolean under, boolean italic,String fontFamaly,Color color, int size,int tipo){        
    String textSelected = null;
    int count = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    try{
        end = seuJTextPane.getSelectionEnd();
        start = seuJTextPane.getSelectionStart();        
        count = seuJTextPane.getSelectedText().length();
        textSelected= seuJTextPane.getSelectedText();            
    }catch(NullPointerException e){

    }


    SimpleAttributeSet attributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();                       
    StyleConstants.setBold(attributes, bold);
    StyleConstants.setUnderline(attributes, under);  
    StyleConstants.setItalic(attributes, italic);
    StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(attributes, 400);
    if(tipo == 1){
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(attributes, fontFamaly);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(attributes,color);
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(attributes, size);         
    }       
    if (textSelected != null) {            
        try {                                           
            seuJTextPane.getStyledDocument().remove(start,count);              

        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Create.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
             seuJTextPane.getStyledDocument().insertString(start,textSelected , attributes);
             seuJTextPane.select(start, end);
             seuJTextPane.setSelectedTextColor(color);                                  
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Create.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }else{            
        try {
             seuJTextPane.getStyledDocument().insertString(tp.getStyledDocument().getLength()," " , attributes);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Create.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Então escolha sua resposta como aceita. Obrigado.