# Como mudar a fonte apenas do texto selecionado na área de texto no Swing (Java)

Tags: java, swing, gui

Estou fazendo um mini editor, mas quando clico no botão de negrito, por exemplo, todo texto muda e eu quero que mude apenas o texto selecionado. E mais, como faço para que quando clicar no botão o texto se tiver normal vá para negrito e vice versa, já que se clicar uma vez não tem como reverter.

Comment: Tenso, sem saber quais componentes você está usando. Se for `JEditorPane`, tem [**essa pergunta/resposta**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92956/4808).

Comment: Estou usando JTextePane